# HomeAway (vrbo.com) API authorization with Oath

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, token

I am trying to use the [VRBO / HomeAway API](https://www.homeaway.com/platform/developer-api) to access reviews for a single property that I am building a website for. I wanted practice with API's and figured that if I use an API for reviews, the list would update itself.

I am building the website with Angular, but for the time being I would like to test the API with the Postman application. The instructions for the API can be found [here](https://www.homeaway.com/platform/developer-api).

I am trying to post to https://ws.homeaway.com/oauth/token for my token as instructed. But my confusion comes from the header. I am told to use a with a 'standard Basic Auth header', which I assume just means 'Authorization' (which is the only authorization header that Postman provides.

However, the API instructions say that this is what the header should look like:

```
Authorization: Basic NTVhODQ4NjItZmE0ZS0xMWU0LWEzMjItMTY5N2Y5MjVlYzdiOjg1MzBmNDZjLWZhNGUtMTFlNC1hMzIyLTE2OTdmOTI1ZWM3Yg==
```

I'm assuming the 'basic' isn't necessary. I get a response from the API with a regular Authorization header, so I think Authorization does fine.

Now, the value of the authorization header is supposed to be:

```
"where the credentials are a base-64 encoded string of your client's id and secret: '<clientId>:<clientSecret>'"
```

So, I was thinking I just had to concatenate my clientId with a ":", followed by ny secret (All of which I have already gotten already)

However,

I only get this error message:

```
{
    "message": "Invalid authorization. Please try again or contact support.",
    "errorCode": "BAD_AUTHORIZATION"
}
```

The API instructions mention:

```
Note: If you do not base-64 encode the client id:secret pair, the request will fail. Additionally, the client id and secret should never be hard coded into code that is provided to end users (mobile applications, etc).
```

Is this something that I have to do? I have read that headers are automatically encoded.

Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Postman does a lot of the work for you. When you choose Basic Auth as the authorization type, it combines the username and password and base-64 encodes it automatically.

[image: basic authorization parameters]

Once you enter the username and password, click Preview Request to generate the request headers. Here you will see the authorization header in the format the API requires.

[image: generated authorization request header]

Click the Send button to submit the request, and you should get a response with the bearer token needed to proceed to the next step of the API process.

[image: API response with bearer token]